# What will happen when using return in run() method?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

Well, the title says it all: What will happen if you would use `return` in the `run()` method implemented from `Runnable`? Will it make the `Thread` die, or not?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but you can't return any value, because `run` is a `void` type.

**Example**

*Using Return to end the thread*

```
public void run()
{
     while(true)
     {
          return;
          // This is fine, and will stop the thread.
     }
}
```

Comment: In this case, it would be better to let OP to learn by trial and error :).

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

When you return from the run() method the thread dies - but the object persists until it becomes unreachable.

See this [article](http://www.roseindia.net/java/thread/life-cycle-of-threads.shtml) about the lifecycle of threads.

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269931/when-does-a-java-thread-reach-the-die-state) related question.

Answer (score 2):

If you put a `return` statement in your runnable the thread dies, and nothing more will happen.

If you need to do something like return a value after thread completion, **have a look at [Callable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)**

It can return a future object that is returned when a thread is finished.

Comment: The poster is asking about if the thread terminates.  Also be careful of the word "exit" since `System.exit(...)` is obviously a different beast.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If you created and started a Thread with that Runnable, then the return statement *will lead to the termination* of the thread. It doesn't cause immediate termination of the thread. For example, any enclosing finally blocks are still executed.

```
new Thread( myRunnable ).start()
```

However, there are other cases where a return statement in a Runnable does not cause termination of the current thread.

For example, you can also call a Runnable directly. Fortunately, the return from the run() method does not kill the thread of the caller.

```
myRunnable.run();
```

And you can put a Runnable into a ThreadPoolExecutor, which *may* run multiple Runnables on a single thread. Return statements in these Runnables do not cause termination of the re-used thread.

```
executorService.submit( myRunnable );
executorService.submit( myOtherRunnable );
```

Comment: The return does make the thread die in the `Thread` context.  Obviously there is other code that is run internal to `Thread` but in terms of the question scope saying that it doesn't is misleading.  The difference between overriding `Thread.run()` and the `if (target!=null) target.run()` method is very subtle.

Comment: @Gray - Clarified first paragraph. Also, consider a return enclosed in a try/finally. After the return statement, the thread continues to execute the finally block, regardless.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted this after the edit above.

Answer (score 1):

It will stop execution and if theres no other references to the Thread object it will eventually be garbage collected.