# Make asynchronous code blocking

Tags: java, asynchronous, blocking

I want to make sure the the main thread is blocked until an asynchronous call is finished.
I am creating a new Thread to execute the async code. 
here is my code:

```
Thread r = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
    asyncCall();
    }
};
r.run();
r.join();
```

`r.join` will block the main thread until r dies.
is that sufficient?
when the thread r actually dies? is it after the async call is done.

Comment: What's the point in creating a Thread then? Does the "asyncCall" call back to indicate completion?

Comment: NB: `r.run()` is the wrong way to invoke a thread's function. You need to use `r.start()`.

Comment: Is `asyncCall` part of some 3rd party API?

Comment: Can you tell us what Framework it is? I guess you'll have to listen on some callback. But we won't know if we don't know the API. Wrapping the starting call will not help if the library starts yet another thread for task execution. You'll end up waiting for the enqueing to finish, not the whole transaction.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to call `thread.start()` and not `thread.run()`, and the answer is yes, `thread.join` blocks until the thread dies.

When does it actually die? [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269931/when-does-a-java-thread-reach-the-die-state)

It is recommended however to use an `executor` and not `Threads` directly.

```
Future<?> future =  executor.submit(()->{});
future.get(); // blocks here
```

Comment: I have the feeling that OP is calling an asynchronous API. So all wrapping in Threads and joining that and the like will be useless in that case.

Comment: @Fildor I totally agree

Answer (score 1):

> r.join will block the main thread until r dies.

Correct.

> is that sufficient?

if the goal is to prevent main thread from continuing execution while `r` is running `ayncCall` then yes.

> when the thread r actually dies? is it after the async call is done.

you can say that the thread finishes execution after `asyncCall` is done. "dying" depends on you definition. the thread may be alive after `asyncCall` is done because the JVM dedcided to re-use it for other purpose. it may not.

ps. you need to call `Thread.start()` , not `Thread.run()`.

Comment: thanks for your clear answer. assuming that the async call is an async update to a database. does my piece of code insure that the update is done before the program continues execution?

Comment: yes, although, if there is nothing between the `Thread.start()` and `Thread.join()` you might as well not create a thread in the first place but just put the function as part of main.