# Is it possible to stop a thread using a custom exception?

Tags: java

I searched at the Internet about stopping a thread. I could only find a deprecated method and a `while` method which doesn't really work.

My idea is declaring a custom exception and putting a `try` in the thread so I can stop that thread by throwing the exception.

Is my idea non-sense and is that why I can't find an answer like this on the Internet?

Comment: It's unclear what you're proposing, but surely you can try it for yourself.

Comment: Throwing an exception only affects the current thread, not a different thread. There is no cross-thread magic involving exceptions. Your Idea won't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly stop the Thread in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10961714/how-to-properly-stop-the-thread-in-java)

Comment: Why a custom exception when there is the [InterruptedException built in](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question:

> [When does a Java Thread reach the 'Die' State](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1269931/when-does-a-java-thread-reach-the-die-state)

(Among others) a thread dies if an exception is thrown that propagates beyond the `run` method.

So yes, you can throw some runtime exception from within your `run` method make sure you don't catch it anywhere in your thread, this will kill your thread.

Comment: unless you write `currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler((t, e) -> t.run());` :)